# Asymptotic normal distribution of MLE estimator using Fisher's information

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, fisher-information

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be independent N(µ, σ$^2$
) random variables. Suppose that µ is known, σ is
unknown and that we want to estimate ψ = log σ.

(a) Find the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\sigma}$ and the asymptotic normal approximation to
the distribution of $\hat{\sigma}$.

(b) Use the delta method to find the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\psi}$ and hence find an approximate 95% confidence interval for ψ.

(c) Explain how the interval in (b) can be used to find an approximate confidence interval
for σ.

I am confused about how to do this because usually we find the MLE of the variance and I'm not sure where to begin. Would appreciate if anyone had any ideas - many thanks.

Comment: What do you know about transformations of MLE? They have a property that’s going to simplify your life.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Dave I've found the MLE for $\sigma^2$ and have just square-rooted it. I'm wondering how to find its asymptotic normal distribution though - if you have time could you suggest whether I should use asymptotic normality with Fisher's information or CLT somehow? Many thanks :)

Comment: Another question - I'm playing around with the delta method but wondering if I should use the actual MLE which has a division by n or the unbiased one which has a division by (n-1). If they've asked about the MLE I would have thought I have to use the one with division by n but it causes issues when taking e.g. $E(\hat{\sigma^2}-\sigma^2)$ - do you know if I'm on the right track or going down a wrong path here?